# What does the (,) mean in the declaration "Public variableName As String(,)"?

Tags: vb.net

I've been coding in VB.Net for about 8 mos on and off for work. I have inherited quite a bit of code to take care of and update. I came across this declaration

Public Employee As String(,)

and have never seen anything like it in all the code I've looked up online over this time. The declaration is inside a module but not inside a sub. A class "Friend Class Mainform" uses it in a call.

The call looks like this: ReadFile(Employee, 10000)

to read an employee file(see below).

I thought it was a deliminator until I looked at the text file that is formatted like this:

> Some Name      P3763 4756
>   Next Name      B8354 2099

Comment: Next Name B8354 2099 should be on the next line

Comment: Two dimensional array.

Comment: So if there was another comma (,,) it would create a 3 dim array?

Comment: That is indeed a 2D array but any code that uses a 2D array to store records is bad code. That's the sort of garbage that first-year students are forced to do in assignments but it should never be done for real. 2D arrays should only be used where each element is a genuine peer, e.g. a grid of students in a classroom. If you are treating each "row" as a record then you should really be using a 1D array or collection of a type with multiuple properties.

Comment: I agree about the garbage code, jmcilhinney. Like I said I inherited the programs to ride herd on. I'll have to look deeper when I have time and see what the intent was. A lot of what I find is lacking elegance and does not have a consistent style so to speak. Thanks for help people!

Comment: How do I close this topic?